# Passar parâmetro com o AJAX para o PHP quando abre uma modal

Tags: php, ajax

Preciso passar o valor dos id de cada link para uma modal.

Está retornando esse erro no console: O que preciso para resolver?

```
custom.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (custom.js:5)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
(anonymous) @ custom.js:5
dispatch @ jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3
```

Estou utilizando o AJAX.

Link

```
<a href="#" id="<?php echo $row['id_usuario'];  ?>" class="push" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#abrir">click</a>
```

AJAX

```
$("a[data-toggle=modal]").click(function() 
{   
    var essay_id = $(this).attr('id');

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax_paciente_id.php',
        data: 'EID='+essay_id,
        success: function(data) 
        {
            $('#abrir').show();
            $('#modalContent').show().html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="abrir" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="abrir" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body modalContent">      


      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

PHP

```
<?

echo $_POST['essay_id']; 

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Jquery Slim não tem a função ajax, você precisa usar a versão completa do Jquery, tenta com esse arquivo:

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: eu troquei pela versão completa, e não retornou  mais o erro, porém não está passando ainda o valor do id.

Comment: @wagner altera sua linha `data: 'EID='+essay_id,` para `data:{EID:essay_id},`

Comment: fiz isso e ainda não passaou o valor do id. Ele parace nem estar chamando o arquivo php ajax_paciente_id.php

Comment: coloca um `console.log()` dentro do success e olha o console pra saber se está chamando ou não, ou se esta retornando erro

Comment: Não retornou nada, o problema deve ser esse que não está chamando o arquivo.

Comment: pode ser também que ele está chamando mas está retornando erro, faz o seguinte: tira o `essay_id` e coloca um valor fixo, e da uma olhada se retorna

Comment: estranho, nao retorna nada tbm fiz assim data:{EID:'ssss'}, será que o problema não está aqui? $("a[data-toggle=modal]").click(function()

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94769/discussion-between-lucas-and-wagner).